# Select the rows matching only one OR condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider a table like this as a very simple example:

```
|----------------------------------|
|              names               |
|----------------------------------|
| id | name_id |  name  | language |
|----------------------------------|
| 1  |    1    |  foo   |    en    |
|----------------------------------|
| 2  |    1    | foose  |    fr    |
|----------------------------------|
```

I want to get the row where name is like 'foo' and language is 'fr' but in the case that there's no row with language 'fr' then fallback to the one where language is 'en'. So my first thought was to write a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE name ILIKE '%foo%' AND (language = 'fr' OR language = 'en')
```

This works fine as long as only one language is available, but when both languages are available it returns both rows, so I added a DISTINCT ON:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name_id) * 
FROM names 
WHERE name ILIKE '%foo%' AND (language = 'fr' OR language = 'en')
```

But this one doesn't work either as it returns the one where language is 'en'.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do like you did with your first query except only select the top one sorted such that "fr" comes before "en".

```
SELECT * 
FROM names 
WHERE name LIKE '%foo%' AND (language = 'fr' OR language = 'en')
ORDER BY language DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY language = 'fr' DESC` works better - allows you to explicitly pick your preferred value - the plain `ORDER BY language DESC` doesn't work if your preferred value is somewhere in the middle of the sort order in case of more than 2 values (e.g. trying to pick out "en" among "en", "fr", "ja").

Comment: The problem is that language is not always 'en' and 'fr', it can be any language iso code, so this won't work. And I don't want just one row but all the rows like %foo% matching one of the languages, so limit won't work either.

Comment: @Amadan's answer makes a lot more sense, looks to me that using it along with the 'distinct on' clause is the right answer

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT`, just `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Amadan not really, 'cause I need all the matching rows, not just one.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s as (
    select *
    from names 
    where
        name ilike '%foo%'
        and
        language in ('fr', 'en')
), fr as (
    select *
    from s
    where language = 'fr'
), en as (
    select *
    from s
    where language = 'en'
)
select *
from fr
union all
select *
from en
where (select count(*) from fr) = 0
```

It will only add the english rows if the french rows count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final implementation, it relies on the @Amadan's comment, so kudos for him. @Clodoaldo Neto approach works as well, but this one looks simpler to me.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name_id) * 
FROM names
WHERE name ILIKE '%foo%' AND language IN ('en', 'fr')
ORDER BY name_id, language = 'fr' DESC
```

And a final tip, if language is nullable (like in my case) the condition should be coalesced since it would return null values which are placed on the top:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name_id) * 
FROM names
WHERE name ILIKE '%foo%' AND language IN ('en', 'fr')
ORDER BY name_id, COALESCE(language = 'fr', FALSE) DESC
```

Comment: It will return english first and then french regardless of the existence of french tranlations.